# Un-monochromatic Arithmetic Progressions

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, extremal-combinatorics

Prove that the set $\{1,2,3,...,2008\}$ can be colored with two colors such that any $18$ term arithmetic progression in this set is not monochromatic.

Comment: This one is also in putnam and beyond btw :)

Comment: I'll look into the book :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Randomly colour the members of the set black and white, independently with probabilities $1/2$ and $1/2$.
The probability that any given $18$-term a.p. in the set is monochromatic is $2^{-17}$.  There are   $117587$ such a.p.'s, and this is less than $2^{17}$.  Thus the expected number of monochromatic a.p.'s  is less than one, which means that it must be possible to have no monochromatic a.p.'s.

Comment: how did you count the A.P's ? Do you think you can prove it is less than $2^{17}$ easily? I really liked your solution by the way.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I don't have that much experience with the probabilistic method yet :)

Comment: @CarryonSmiling To count the A. P is just $\sum_{d = 1}^{118} (2008 - 17d)$

Comment: The number of progressions of form $a,a+d\dots a+15d$ is $2008-17d$. So using the gauss sum you get $\sum_{i=1}^{118}2008-15d=118\times2008-17\times59\times119=117587\leq 131072=2^{17}$