# Arithmetic progression of ten terms is not monochromatic

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic-progressions, probabilistic-method

**Problem**

For $n=2020$, show that we can 4-colour the elements of the set $ V = \{1, \dots , n\}$ in such a way that any arithmetic progression of ten terms is not monochromatic.

**What I have so far**

Let $S_{10}$ be the set of all arithmetic progressions of length ten in  $V$. Let $E$ be the event that no set in $S_{10}$ is monochromatic. Then $P(E) = 1 - P(\bar{E})$, where
$\bar{E}$ is the event that some set in $S_{10}$ is monochromatic . We have

$P(\bar{E}) = \bigcup_{i = 1}^{|S_{10}|} P(E_i)$

where $E_i$ is the event corresponding to  $i$th set of $S_{10}$ being monochromatic. We then have

$P(E_i) = \frac{4}{4^{10}} = \frac{1}{4^{9}}$

Now, there are a most $n^2 = 2020^2$ arithmetic progressions 
 by the union bound $P( \bar{E}  ) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{2020^2} P(E_i) = \frac{2020^2}{4^9} \approx 15$, which is no help as any probability must lie in $[0,1]$.

This is where I'm stuck, as I'm not sure which bound to use. Also, this is one of the first Exercises in of our graduate module so I don't think we're expected to invote any power theorems or the like.

(There is a similar question about 2-colouring arithmetic progressions of size 18 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872264/un-monochromatic-arithmetic-progressions) however I don't understand the method of counting the APs, at least not enough to extend it to the lenth 10 case)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An a.p. of $10$ terms is $(a, a+d, \ldots, a + 9 d)$ where $a \ge 1$, $d \ge 1$ and
$a + 9 d \le n$.  Thus $9 d = (a + 9 d) - a \le n - 1$, so $d \le \lfloor (n-1)/9 \rfloor$.  Given such $d$, there are $n-9d$ possibilities for $a$.  Thus if $m = \lfloor (n-1)/9 \rfloor$, the number of 
a.p.'s of $10$ terms is
$$ \sum_{d=1}^m (n - 9 d) = m n - 9 \frac{m (m+1)}{2} $$
In this case $m=224$ and the number of a.p.'s is $225680$.

Now consider a random $4$-colouring of $V$.  For each a.p. of $10$ terms the probability of it being monochromatic is $1/4^9 = 1/262144$.  The probability that at least one such a.p. is monochromatic is at least $1 - 225680/262144 > 0$.  Therefore some $4$-colouring has no monochromatic a.p. of $10$ terms.

Comment: +1 Typo: $m=224$.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.